# How to teach multiple levels of French?

Tags: teaching

I am a 5/6 and 7/8 split French teacher with students ranging from anglophone, all the way to francophone.

I am having difficulty finding ways to make lessons that will include the whole class, and I feel like I'm either way above the level, or way below the level of half of my class.

Does anyone have any techniques that may be of use to me? All suggestions are very appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a question about academia (5/6 and 7/8 sounds like lower school level rather than university level and certainly not like graduate level.)

Comment: Could you please explain "5/6 and 7/8 split"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest studying the techniques used in [one-room schools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-room_school).

The idea is not to even try to teach one lesson to the whole class. Instead, you get small groups doing work appropriate to their level, while moving around and giving instruction to groups as needed. Generally, the younger students will need the most attention.

For example, you could set a group of the most advanced students to first translate a passage individually, and then discuss, in French, the differences between their translations. If they disagree about a translation and cannot resolve it themselves, they will need your help for a few minutes. Gradually make the passages more difficult, so they go on learning. Periodically, explain an advanced point of French grammar or usage, and then set passages to translate in each direction using it. You can tell them to use the new structure when translating to French.

You can also use more advanced students to help teach. Trying to explain e.g. a tricky point of grammar can be a good way of clarifying it in one's own mind.

Meanwhile, you can be working with the beginners, who will need more direct instruction.

Comment: This is a good idea, thank you! I will definitely use this method.